# Можно ли определить логику в приложении в зависимости от версии framework установленного на машине?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

Доброго времени суток!

Хочу сделать в program.cs в main вилку и инициализировать приложение по-разному, в зависимости от наличия того или иного framework

То есть, проверяю наличие framework 4.0, если установлен, то использую окно написанное под него, если нет, но есть 3.5, то другое. Если и того нет, то выдать ошибку пользователю и попросить установить необходимые компоненты.

Это вообще реально?

Ps: написать одну библиотеку/приложение под разные фрэймворки реально или не может быть собран модуль универсально и нужно их физически разделять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее можно попробовать такое провернуть.

Указать в файле конфигурации несколько предпочтительных версий .net framework для приложения в порядке приоритета: [элемент <supportedRuntime>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/jj152935(v=vs.110).aspx)

Далее при запуске программно определить под какой версией запустилось приложение:
[см. "Поиск текущей версии среды выполнения путем запроса класса Environment в коде"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh925568.aspx)

После этого создав разные библиотеки для разных сборок можно подключить нужную dll с требуемым кодом через assemblies и использовать в коде уже ее.

Answer (score 0):

Можно узнать версию .Net через реестр и уже анализировать эту информацию